# How do I tell if above my kitchen hood is water damage or just paint fading?

Tags: kitchens, paint, water-damage, range-hood

The paint above my hood seems to be breaking off. I'm not sure if this is water damage or gravity with the hood sinking from where it was installed. I don't feel any wetness, but my master bath is above the kitchen.

Any suggestions about what I should do to evaluate further / fix it?

[image: above hood right]

[image: above hood left]

Comment: It looks like water stains at the edge of something above(a small shower pan?).  With a bathroom above, a good chance the ceiling or floor above will need opening.  Drywall is usually easier to fix.

Comment: If it was gravity (e.g., hood pulling down on the ceiling drywall) you would see cracks but not discoloration.